# Evaluating $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^{+}} \frac{x}{\ln^2 x}$

Tags: analysis, limits, logarithms

How can I find:

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{x}{\ln^2 x} $$

I know that the limit is $0$. I tried sandwich theorem but I don't know what could be bigger.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. I have changed the formatting of the title so as to make it take up less vertical space -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance. Moreover, please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/title-and-latex).

Comment: @user83782: $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \ln^2 x = +∞$ , so $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac 1{\ln^2 x} =0$ , this gives your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: You need only consider what happens when $x$ is close to $0$, and as long as $0<x\le 1$, you have

$$\frac{x}{\ln^2x}\le\frac1{\ln^2x}\;.$$

(I’m assuming that by $\ln^2x$ you mean $\left(\ln x\right)^2$, as the other possible meaning, $\ln\ln x$, is undefined for $0<x<1$.)

Comment: Ah I see! I didn't noticed that this is decreasing function. 
Thank you! How can I use l’Hospital’s rule? It's $ \frac{0}{\infty} $

Comment: @user83782: You can’t: I’m about to head off to bed, and that was a slip of the mind. :-) You actually don’t need anything at all, unless you’re required to be a bit formal, since the numerator approaches $0$ and the denominator is bounded away from $0$ once $x$ gets close to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it can be done using the sandwich theorem.

---

The quantity is positive, so $0$ is a lower bound.

For $x < 1$, we have that $\dfrac{x}{\ln^2 x} < \dfrac{1}{\ln^2 x}$.

Now since $\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+} \ln x = -\infty$ (which is a consequence of the fact that it equals $\lim\limits_{x\to0^+} - \ln \frac1x$ and that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \ln x = \infty$), we obtain:

$$\lim_{x\to0^+} \frac1{\ln^2 x} = 0$$

and we conclude by the sandwich theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Just note that,

$$ \lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{x}{\ln^2(x)}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}x\, \lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{1}{\ln^2(x)}=0.0=0. $$